Selected for H1B but never intends to find employment in the US
If a Canadian applicant was selected for a H1B lottery but never intends to find employment in the US, will the H1B status expire after about 3 years? If not, when will it expire? Thanks.

What does "activated its status" mean? You can only have "status" while in the US.

@user102008 I edited it. Thanks.

You cannot obtain a non-immigrant status without first being admitted to the U.S. You should ask what you actually want to ask instead of using technical terms with specific meanings.

@xngtng Ok, let's say the person stepped on the soil in the US for 3 days and went back to Canada, how does the timeframe for the 3 year limit apply?

An employer must file a petition for the foreign worker and has the petition approved before the foreign worker may be admitted on an H1B status. If the H1B is capped for the employer/employment (most jobs with most employers are capped), the employer must register the prospective petition in a lottery and can only file the petition if the registration is selected in the lottery.
In any case, you must have an employment offer to be eligible for H1B status. You cannot be selected in a lottery without an employment offer and an employer registering for you. If others told you otherwise, they are either ignorant or in many cases trying to scam you.
The H1B petition is generally approved for a maximum of three years from the date of employment indicated on the approval notice (I-797). The notice contains an expiry date of the approved petition.
The H1B status is granted upon admission into the United States as an H1B worker, generally until the end of the approved petition (or the expiry of your passport or travel document if earlier). The three-year "limit" of the grant of status is a result of the limited validity period of the approved petition. You may only be admitted into the U.S. with an H1B status if your H1B approval notice is valid (with a 10-day grace period before the employment starts).
The legal limit on H1B status is a maximum of six years in total, including extensions and time spent with other H or L status. Days spent outside of the United States may be recaptured (i.e. not counted in the six-year limit) when filing a new petition (e.g. for extension).
The H1B status is contingent on the continuation of the petitioned employment following the conditions of work (including place of work) specified in the petition with the Labor Condition Application.

So you are saying the 3 year limit does not begin until a person finds employment here in the US? Will the H1B status expire after some time if the person never intents to find employment in the US even if that person was selected for H1B? Thanks.

@HelloDarkWorld H1B requires an employer-sponsored petition. You cannot be "selected" for H1B without an employment offer.

Then for those who were selected in the lottery, what is that called?

@HelloDarkWorld You can only enter the lottery with an employment offer.

In fact it is the employer who registers in the lottery and then files the petition for the foreign worker.

What if the employer files but the foreign worker never got selected?

@HelloDarkWorld The employer cannot file a petition for a capped H1B without their registration for the foreign worker being selected in the lottery. If the registration is not selected, then there is no petition and no H1B for the worker. I am really not sure what you are asking here.

@xngtng I think they are asking about a somewhat common scam where a site alleges someone von the visa lottery and they just have to file papers and find employment.

@Trish I added a small warning in the answer.
